# Bootstrap fix top navbar

Tags: html, navbar, flask-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get familiar with working with Flask bootstrap. However, one thing confuses me. I'm using http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top .

It tells me to add: `body { padding-top: 70px; }`

However, where does it want me to add it? I've added it manually to my html file, which works, but I'm working with blocks.

This is what it looks like now, which isn't the way it is suppose to be, I guess?

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: it is optional if u have fixed nav bar

Comment: Yeah I noticed, but else my navbar overlaps with the text, so its kinda needed in my case.

Comment: post u r full code in codepen or similar

Comment: What do you mean by 'I'm working with blocks'? Is this part relevant to understanding where you need to add the CSS?

Comment: I'm not sure.. I'm using the way shown here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PE9ZGniSDW8&t=10s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place you are trying to add it looks fine. It just needs to be in any CSS file that gets loaded after the bootstrap CSS file. If you're inlining the CSS in your HTML, as it seems you are, and you're loading the bootstrap CSS correctly, from the `<head>` section of your page, then it will be loaded after the bootstrap, so that's ok. The only thing to bear in mind is that if you refactor the CSS into a separate file, the `<rel>` call to the page CSS file should go *after* the bootstrap CSS call.

What Flask calls blocks seem to essentially be templates, similar to those in backbone, ruby, mustache templates etc. When using these it can be helpful to let your page load in localhost, and inspect the source, so you'll be able to see how the final page loads, and  where everything is loaded relative to other parts. However, the same principles should apply. With Flash you should be using the `head` block to load in the `<head>` section of your page.

Comment: the thing is; im trying to use blocks and kinda wanted put everything into that.

Comment: Do you mean https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ultimate-blocks-theme-builder-WB0DDD518 ? Or something else? I thought you just meant CSS blocks... Which was a little confusing since if you are using CSS I would have assumed you'd always be using blocks.

Comment: ah sorry, its prolly confusing but.. i linked a video of what way im using it. I use block as in: {% block body %} bla bla {% endblock %}

Comment: Oh, of course. Let me take another look. Probably partly the explanation and partly me overlooking some of the context... wait, I don't see a video. It looks like you're using templates... is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, im using templates. This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PE9ZGniSDW8&t=10s

Comment: Does the answer now fully address your question, Nerotix?

Comment: sorry, been away. I think it solves my question indeed. What u r saying is that block head is the same as <head> in normal html code, correct?